# Why is my time to first byte so much and how to reduce it?

Tags: php, css, performance, caching, pagespeed

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I am using PHP to include header and footer. All my content is static and I am not making any database queries or performing any heavy calculation. I also have turned on the compression. I understand that turning on compression increases TTFB but every other file is also being compressed like `bootstrap.min.css`. 
Why is is that just files from my domain have long TTFB? Here is another screenshot from Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Check how long does it take to run your php script. It might be because of a bad server configuration and not about your code.

Comment: @FiratAkandere what do you mean by running my PHP script? I don't exactly understand.

Comment: Well I just re-read your issue. 762ms is TOO HIGH just for including 2 files. Compression is not going to decrease TTFB, it' decreases Content Download. I suggest you to get in touch with your hosting provider, I think the problem is the server you use.

Comment: Can you reproduce this locally by hosting the page on your workstation? This is most likely a remote resource issue (latency, network, resources), not a php one.

Comment: @JustinT. Do you mean putting it all on localhost using a service like Xampp and then check the TTFB?

Comment: Yes, you should develop/debug on your workstation, to reduce all external troubles.

Comment: I just ran a test and the TTFB was 5ms. So, I guess it has something to do with server configuration. Are there some things that I can change on the server that are under my control? I am on shared host.

Comment: Shared hosting means very little control on network conditions, so sadly no, you better move to a closer/faster hosting company.